# Sencha Command - @import 'sencha-touch/default/all' not found

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

When I run the sencha command like so:

**sencha app build production**

I get an error which points to the following line in app.scss:

**@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';**

In my app I have the following folder:

**\App\touch\resources\themes\stylesheets\sencha-touch\default**

But there is no 'all' folder. Is my application structure broken or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error might be generated because there's no `_all.scss` inside

> touch\resources\themes\stylesheets\sencha-touch\default

Contents of _all.scss are

```
@import 'core';
@import 'widgets';
```

Check application structure again or just create `_all.scss` manually and see if it solves problem.

Comment: Yes, the structure was wrong which was confusing me. Any idea why sencha-touch/default/all picks up a file with a prepended underscore (_all.scss)?

Comment: don't know the extact reason, but maybe build tools use this type of naming convention. They just ignore `_` when reading and still access the file in build process.